# Show that the $Y^3-Y+1$ splits completely into linear factors in $E[Y]$ and find these factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am working through some past exam papers, and I have some conceptual questions that I need to clear up regarding this question:

The full question is:

> Let $\mathbb{F_3}= \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}}$ be the field with 3
>   elements and $f=X^3+X+1$
>
> (a) Show that f is irreducible
>
> (b) How many elements are there in the field $E = F[X]/(f)$?
>
> (c) Determine the inverse of the element $a = X + (f) \in E$
>
> (d) Show that $Y^3-Y+1$ splits into linear factors in $E[Y]$ and find
>   these factors

$(a)$ is straight forward.

$(b)$For this one, I simply wrote all the polynomials in $\mathbb{F_3}$ with degree $< 3$ and checked which ones were irreducible. Explicitly I found 13, which were: $0, 1, 2, x, x+1, x+2, 2x, 2x+1, 2x+2, x^2+1, x^2+x+1, x^2+2x+2, 2x^2+x+1$

I have a few questions here:

$(1)$ Just to be sure, am I correct to say that the element $2x+2$ is different than say $2(x+1)$? Why would this be so?

$(2)$ Also, as a check, I should always find the number of elements to be some $p^n$, $p$ prime and $n \ge 1$ right?

$(3)$ Is there supposed to be a better way to do this than to just write everything out?

$(c)$ For this part, I have a bit of confusion, I used the Euclidean algorithm to work through $X^3-X+1$ and $X$, to get:

$$1 = (X^3-X+1)-(X^2-1)(X)$$ but taking $-(X^2-1)$ in mod $3$, this is $2X^2+1$, is this correct?

I'm a bit confused, because $2X^2+1$ is not an element in my field.

On one hand, if the inverse of $X$ was another irreducible, then would that mean $1$ is not irreducible? But one the other, the inverse of $X$ is something that is not in my field?

I know I am missing something that is probably very elementary, but if someone could help explain this to me that would be great.

For part (d) I know this is similar to this question: [Splitting of polynomial into linear factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296456/splitting-of-polynomial-into-linear-factors) but I have some confusion again. I know that $Y$ is a zero of $X^3-X+1$, but I'm really not sure how to go about doing this..

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Edit where you introduce $f$: it says $f=X^3+X+1$ which is not irreducible.

Comment: $2(X+1)=2X+2$. There is no reason for them to be different. You're looking for all quadratics with three elements as choices for coefficients. Thus, there should be $3^3$ elements.

Comment: In (b), as mentioned by Taylor, you are not looking for irreducibles.  And if you were looking for irreducibles $x^2+x+1$ would not be in the list.

Comment: I think I may have made a mistake in understanding the question. This question is from an exam a couple of years ago, so I thought maybe just some notation was different - but I was thinking that $E = F[X]/(f)$, was the same as $E = F[X]/f(x)F[X]$...so these are actually different things?

Comment: I think I was confusing this question with $f(x) = x^3-x+1$ and the Quotient ring $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]/f(x)\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$, where the elements are the coset representatives? I think this question above we did not cover in my class. The question I mention here and the above is totally different right? - Or am I going crazy?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm catching up with you. The ideal $(f)$ is the same as $fF[X]$ for commutative rings.

Comment: But aren't the elements of the field $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]/f(x)\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$ cosets? And aren't the representatives of these, the irreducibles of degree $2$ or less?

Comment: They are cosets, and the representatives are the polynomials of degree 2 or less, but they do not have to be irreducible. You're looking for all possible remainders you can get when dividing polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ by $f(x)$. For example, $X^2+1$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but there is no other quadratic that it is congruent to modulo $f(x)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24793/discussion-between-taylor-and-jackreacher).

Answer (score 1):

For (b), think of ordered triplets: $(\alpha , \beta , \gamma )$ corresponding to $\alpha X^2 +\beta X+\gamma$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}_3$. $E$ consists of all such triplets.

You have (c) correct, and $2X^2+1$ is in the field.

For the last bit, $X$ is a root of $Y^3-Y+1$. Thus, $Y^3-Y+1=(Y-X)q$ for some quadratic $q\in E[Y]$. You can find $q$ via long division. Now you may proceed to factor $q$ using methods for solving quadratics such as completing the square or the quadratic formula, but keep in mind what field you are in.

Comment: Unless the OP made a typo, I can't see why $X+(f)$ (not $X$) is a root of $Y^3-Y+1$ in $E$.

Comment: @user26857 It's probably the typo: $f=X^3-X+1$, not $f=X^3+X+1$. And I've gotten into the habit of leaving off the ideals for the cosets. That didn't seem to cause any ambiguity.